# are there editing commands for voice to text?

Tags: audio, voice-dictation

My iPhone, iPad, and Mac each has the same, excellent voice to text input.  But I have never discovered if there are any voice editing commands, such as:  delete last word, or replace 3rd from last word, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac go to System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Scroll the list on the left all the way down to Dictation and setup your Dictation commands including those for editing text.

[image]
[image]